# Perl scp a file from windows to Linux

Tags: perl, scp

This Perl script run on Windows, I am trying to scp a file from local machine to a Linux machine, it doesn't print any error but don't copy the file.

```
use Net::SCP qw(scp);
$source = 'c:\temp\a.txt';
$destination = '/tmp';
$scp = Net::SCP->new( "$ip", "$user" ) or die "cannot scp $!";
print "scp $source $destination";
$scp->scp($source, $destination);
```

Comment: What is the return value of `$scp->scp(...)`? What is the value of `$scp->{errstr}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Net::SCP documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~ivan/Net-SCP-0.08/SCP.pm) has two examples of how to call `scp()`:

```
use Net::SCP qw(scp iscp);
scp($source, $destination);

$scp = new Net::SCP;
$scp->scp($source, $destination);
```

You'll note that neither version shows how to specify the hostname, username, or password, or whether the copy operation is local-to-remote or remote-to-local.

The fact is that the Net::SCP documentation doesn't do a very good job of describing how to use scp(). Looking at the [source code for the module](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/IVAN/Net-SCP-0.08/SCP.pm) reveals that:

1. The `scp()` subroutine doesn't make use of any of the values passed to the Net::SCP constructor.
2. scp() invokes the `scp` command-line utility, passing the source and destination arguments to that program *verbatim*.

So, the correct way to specify hostname, username, password, and the copy direction is the same way as for [the scp command line utility](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/scp.1?query=scp&sec=1). Your `$source` and `$destination` values have to follow the general form accepted by the `scp` program. Assuming you're trying to do a local-to-remote transfer, you should try something like this:

```
$source = 'c:\temp\a.txt';
$destination = "${user}\@${ip}:/tmp";
$scp = new Net::SCP;
$scp->scp($source, $destination);
```

This produces a destination with of the form "user@1.2.3.4:/tmp", which is the form accepted by the `scp` program.

If you're trying to do a remote-to-local copy, then the "${user}\@${ip}:" string should be prepended to $source rather than $destination. Note the "@" is preceded by a backslash here because it's special in double-quoted strings.

As an aside, if you invoke the `scp` program with two local pathnames, it calls the system's file-copy utility to do a local copy operation. So you've probably copied your source filename to C:\tmp or a similar place on your local system.

Comment: Thanks Kenster, the error is `'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, should I install scp program on my local PC ?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to have a copy of the "scp" command-line utility installed and available in your command path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scp = Net::SCP->new( "$ip", "$user" ) or die "cannot scp $!";
$scp = new Net::SCP;
```

calls the `Net::SCP` constructor twice. The second time, it calls it without a hostname or userid, does not check the return value, and overwrites your previous, correct-looking call. Delete the second of these lines.

Comment: Sure it did, it just hasn't helped enough to be noticeable yet :-)

Comment: Updated the script in my question to remove the extra constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing for success in calling the `scp` object's constructor, but you aren't testing for success in actually performing an `scp` action.

This line could be improved upon:

```
$scp->scp($source, $destination);
```

The documentation for the module states that `scp` returns false on failure, and sets the `errstr` attribute.  So you could change that line as follows:

```
$scp->scp($source, $destination) or die 'scp failed: ', $scp->{errstr};
```

By so doing, you should get useful diagnostic information, which is the only way to really know what has to happen to fix the problem.

Also, unrelated to your problem but worth mentioning:  `use Net::SCP qw(scp);` is wrong because it's importing the `scp` function into your calling namespace.  The reason this is wrong is that you are using the object-oriented "method call" invocation of `scp` (in other words, `$scp->scp(...)`.  The method call means of invoking `scp` doesn't require anything be imported into your calling namespace.

Comment: yes, stupid me, thanks, that help identifying the problem, I get the the error message printed now `scp failed: 'scp' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, As kenster mentioned, its trying to invoke the local scp command, I thought its going to use Perl's and I don't need to install scp on my local PC.

Comment: Seeing the error message is almost always progress. :)